# ng-show/ng-hide not happening instantaneously

Tags: angularjs

I have a "Record" button and a "Stop" button. The Record button has an ng-hide="recording" and the Stop button has an ng-show="recording"

I set $scope.recording = true when "Record" is clicked, but for a noticeable amount of time (~100ms), both the "Record" and "Stop" buttons are visible before the Record button disappears.

This behavior is also happening on various other buttons with similar relationships. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? (I am currently on angular 1.2.18, could that be an issue?)

Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code that replicates this issue?

Comment: Please update to post your method that is changing your values, but in psychically debugging, how much processing is your code doing before letting the digest cycle run?

Comment: Do you have any CSS that adds a transition delay to the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your followups. I really appreciate how eager the community is to help. I found out that the issue was due to an older version of ngAnimate. I'm not quite sure why, but upgrading it to the latest version helped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the cause of your problem. In any case here is a better way to implement your problem situation.

In your case, there is no need to use the scope variables to manipulate the DOM elements.

Instead,

```
<button ng-click="recordStopToggle = !recordStopToggle" ng-hide="recordStopToggle">Record</button>
<button ng-click="recordStopToggle = !recordStopToggle" ng-show="recordStopToggle">Stop</button>
```

You can also use toggle class using ng-class to show/hide like so,

```
<button ng-class="{true: 'btn-primary', false: 'btn-danger'}[!recordStopToggle]" ng-click="recordStopToggle = !recordStopToggle;">{{!recordStopToggle && 'Record' || 'Stop'}}</button>
```

If in case you need to call another function from this button then you can just do so in `ng-click`

```
ng-click="editBtnToggle = !editBtnToggle; yourFunction();"
```

---

In this way the time delay you were mentioning should not be a problem.

Please let me know if you had any issues with this solution.